# write unit test case for this method returning RxJava Future

Tags: java, unit-testing, rx-java2, junit4, vert.x

Can any one please help me to write a unit test case for this method returning RxJava Future object , I am able to write and mock for a method returning Single.

```
public Future<JsonObject> fetchVendorDetailsVendorIdAsFuture(String serviceURI, Map<String, String> headerMap) {


    if(vbConnectorCircuitBreaker == null){
        vbConnectorCircuitBreaker= CircuitBreakers.getVbConnectorCircuitBreaker();
    }
    return vbConnectorCircuitBreaker.execute(future -> {
        // get ok http client
        OkHttpClient client = okHTTPClientHelper.getOkHTTPClient();

        if(client != null){
            try{
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
                Headers headers = Headers.of(headerMap);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(serviceURI)
                        .get()
                        .headers(headers)
                        .build();

                Call call = client.newCall(request);
                call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                            throws IOException {
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject(jsonData);
                        future.complete(jsonObject);
                    }

                    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {

                        future.complete(null);
                    }
                });
            } catch(Exception exception) {

                future.complete(null);
            }
        } else {
            future.complete(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this method is quite big and contains if-statements and a try-catch-term. This is difficult to unit test because there are too many branches to cover. Perhabs you could refactor it to reduce the number of code branches? That would make it easier to think of a test small enough to write.

Comment: Also, you are asking for a world of hurt by trying to pass `null` through a `Future` or using RxJava. Don't do that.

Comment: @Erunafailaro Sure I will refactor it but , I only want to know how can I test the method returning Future<JsonObject> , I tried working with Single and able to do it with testSubscriber as below , but not Future                                                              
  Single<String> stringSingle = vbConnectorServiceProviderMock.getUserIdForLoginId(loginId);
        stringSingle.subscribe(testSubscriber);
        testSubscriber.assertCompleted();

        testSubscriber.assertValue(expectedVal);

Comment: How is this related to RxJava?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using okhttp's MockWebServer.

That way, your `Call` can emit a real http request and you will be able to handle the server's response.

You can create the mocked server's response yourself using `mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse() ... )`

There are a lot of different ways to write tests for this kind of problem and here is my suggestion:

```java
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.RecordedRequest;

// other imports omitted

@ExtendWith(VertxExtension.class)
@Slf4j
public class VendorDetailsTest {


    private VendorDetailsVerticle sut;

    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        sut = new VendorDetailsVerticle();
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteService(final Vertx vertx, final VertxTestContext testContext)
        throws InterruptedException {

        // given -----
        final JsonObject serverResponsePayload = new JsonObject().put("futureCompleted", true);
        mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setBody(serverResponsePayload.encode())
            .setResponseCode(200)
            .setHeader("content-type", "application/json"));

        // when -----
        final Future<JsonObject> jsonObjectFuture = 
            sut.fetchVendorDetailsVendorIdAsFuture(mockWebServer.url("/").toString(), new HashMap<>());

        // then -----
        final RecordedRequest recordedRequest = mockWebServer.takeRequest();
        assertEquals("GET", recordedRequest.getMethod());
        assertEquals(1, mockWebServer.getRequestCount());
        testContext.assertComplete(jsonObjectFuture)
                           .map(val -> {
                               assertEquals("{'futureCompleted': true}", val.encode());
                               testContext.completeNow();
                               return val;
                           })
                           .onComplete(onComplete -> {
                               assertTrue(onComplete.succeeded());
                               log.info("done");
                           })
                           .onFailure(onError -> Assertions.fail());

    }
}
```

This test will of course need a little bit of customization to run in your project, but I hope it will give a picture on how to approach testing RxJava's futures.